# ConTeXt mailing list subscription

Tags: context

I have been trying to subscribe to the ConTeXt user mailing list (ntg-context@ntg.nl) for two weeks now. However, there is no response from the list admin. The latest entries in the list archive date back to April '23. Is the list still being actively maintained?

Comment: Yes it is, but you are right something seems to be wrong. I'll also send an email, maybe it works better if somebody who is on the list sends it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last system upgrade broke the mailman installation on the server, and it is only slowly coming back to life.

Comment: Thanks for fixing, Taco!